# Timepieces and Moving Parts

Tags: riddle, time

The sundial keeps time with the fewest number of moving parts.

Which timepiece has the most moving parts?

Comment: Upvoting, because I don't think this deserves the downvote.   an hourglass is a reasonable answer to this riddle, without getting too tricky and exotic.

Comment: Does anyone have an estimate for the number of moving electrons in my smartphone?

Comment: Should we narrow it down to timepieces made by humans? Otherwise, one could argue the entire universe as a means of keeping time for beings powerful enough.

Comment: You could argue that. If we were in scifi.SE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, one with a lot of moving parts would be an hourglass. Each grain of salt is a 'moving part'. Just scale it up as big as is needed to trump other options.

Comment: Many kinds of timepiece can be "scaled up as big as needed to trump other options"

Comment: Mainly just added that to avoid the obvious question of 'I have this really small one minute hourglass, there's not that much sand in it.'

Comment: If we're counting each discrete particle of a fluid as separate moving parts, then a [water clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_clock) beats an hourglass by about 20 orders of magnitude. But if you argue "each drop of water counts as a moving part, not each molecule", then the hourglass goes back to winning.

Comment: Same mechanic could be applied for each molecule within the grain of sand. Or by extension, each molecule within a move piece of a traditional clock could count aswell. Don't think we need to go there.

Comment: Yeah, it's a deep rabbit hole of "Molecules weakly attracted to each other by polar forces _do_ count as separate moving parts, but molecules bound by strong covalent bonds _don't_ count" and then the question becomes highly subjective based on where you draw the line.

Comment: guys, guys... stars! hydrogen atoms etc...

Comment: If you take each molecule as one moving part, the sundial has by far the most moving parts! Given the giant size of the sun, I guess that this also holds for each other granularity that could possibly work with a fluid.

Comment: "The atoms themselves don't keep time... the mechanical parts observing the atoms do." -- generalcrispy (Substitute atoms with grains, and mechanical with eye)

Answer (score 8):

A water clock.

A typical water clock might contain about $10^{25}$ water molecules. Compare to a paltry $10^{9}$ for an [hourglass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2659). (Give or take a couple of orders of magnitude)

Answer (score 5):

The system of stars (including the sun) which we have used since antiquity.

Or maybe the body clock: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_rhythm

The myriad year clock perhaps. It can be wound once every year and over 1000 parts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myriad_year_clock

Comment: The universe/cosmos/stars is a decent answer, but I'm looking for something specifically designed to keep time.

Comment: @generalcrispy are you sure this is a "puzzle"? at the moment it's seeming like a trivia quiz :p

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's a trivia quiz. I'm learning more about timepieces than I expected to!

Answer (score 2):

The universe?

It keeps time as it contains all other known timepieces and it kind of defines what time is.

Answer (score 1):

A [floral clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floral_clock).‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

It might have hundreds of flowers on its hands, all moving together.

Answer (score -1):

An atomic clock: if you count each atom as a time-keeping part, it has a gigantic number of these, all moving.

Comment: The atoms themselves don't keep time... the mechanical parts observing the atoms do. Good guess, but there is actually a timepiece that has way more parts than an atomic clock.