# Millions of parts. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> I contain thousands of moving parts, perhaps more.
> Yet a cousin of mine may be solid throughout.
>
> Despite my relative's simplicity,
> He often functions as well as I do.

***Who am I?***

Comment: May be solid throughout? Does it mean that it might be solid throught?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the same vein as as
[Element118's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/30198/18129),

> **If I were** an hourglass, 
>  **my cousin would be** a sundial.

I contain thousands of moving parts, perhaps more.

> Thousands of grains of sand.

Yet a cousin of mine may be solid throughout.

> A sundial is often a single piece of material.

Despite my relative's simplicity,

> Simple as an hourglass is,
>  a sundial doesn't even need to be turned over to work.

He often functions as well as I do.

> As long as the sun shines.

See also:

> [Puzzling SE:Timepieces
>   and Moving Parts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2652/18129) 
>  http://www.cartalk.com/content/pondering-two-inventions?question 
>  http://www.cartalk.com/content/pondering-two-inventions?answer 
>  http://community.cartalk.com/discussion/2250814/bogus-puzzler-answer-3-26

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/

Comment: Thanks, @f'', the previous question is now linked in the answer

Answer (score 3):

I would guess (probably a bad guess):

> Analog watch

I contain thousands of moving parts, perhaps more.

> Analog watch has lots of moving parts.

Yet a cousin of mine may be solid throughout.

> Cousin: Digital watch

Despite my relative's simplicity,

> I think it is simpler to read the time directly on a digital watch.

He often functions as well as I do.

> Both are watches so they do the same thing.

Comment: A watch doesn't contain thousands of moving parts.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of a stretch, but how about:

> Hard disk drive (HDD) vs. Solid-state drive (SSD)? When SSD first came out they were more prone to failure than HDD, so it would make sense that SSD "**often** functions as well" as a HDD, but not all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> [Thrackan Sal-Solo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thrackan_Sal-Solo), first cousin to the better-known [Han Solo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo).

I contain thousands of moving parts, perhaps more.

> Most people do.

Yet a cousin of mine may be solid throughout

> [image: Han Popsicle]

Despite my relative's simplicity,

> In the original Star Wars screenplay, Han Solo was described as "simple, sentimental and cocksure of himself"

He often functions as well as I do

> Both were criminals-turned-resistance-leaders of resistances which ultimately overthrew their oppressors.

Answer (score 1):

Might you be:

> An electric shaver?

I contain thousands of moving parts, perhaps more.

> They have internal motors and can have multiple cutting blades, swirly multi-head circular whisker-whackers, *etc*.

Yet a cousin of mine may be solid throughout.

> Just a simple cut-throat razors although you can get fancier with safety-razors,  *etc*.

Despite my relative's simplicity,
He often functions as well as I do.

> *Often* in the sense that most people go to a well-trusted barber to be shaved with a cut-throat razor and it *often* all goes nicely according to plan, but when it doesn't...